# Power series for $\cos(n\theta)$ in terms of $\sin^{2i}(\theta/2)$?

Tags: trigonometry, power-series

Does anybody know an expression for the weights in
$$
 \cos(n\theta) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i \sin^{2i}(\theta/2)
$$
I checked the standard sources (Abramowitz & Stegun, Gradshteyn & Rhyzik) and could not find it.
Of course $c_0=1$ and it's easy to see that $c_1=-2n^2$ and $c_n=(-1)^n 2^{2n-1}$. One can deduce that $c_{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}2^{2(n-1)}n$ and $c_{n-2}=(-1)^n 2^{2n-5} n (2n-3)$, but I have not been able to derive expressions for the other coefficients or find a general expression for $c_i,\; 0 < i < n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $\theta/2 = u$, then as $\sin^2 u = 1 - \cos^2 u$ you have:
$$
\cos 2 n u = \sum_{i \ge 0} d_i \cos^{2 i} u
$$
and that  looks much like [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) to me...

Comment: Good point. I'll look into it.

Comment: In case anybody needs this, too, the answer is:$c_{n,i}=(-1)^i 2^{2i-1} 2n \frac{(n+i-1)!}{(n-i)!(2i)!}$ where $c_{n,i}$ is the $i$th coefficient in the expansion of $\cos(n\theta)$.